# Vagrant was unable to connect to the virtual machine VirtualBox

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I can't connect to the virtual machine.

Could you help me with my problem?

Here is the log from GitBash:

py@cpython MINGW64 ~/courses/profiles-rest-api (master)

$ vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> default: Box 'ubuntu/bionic64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...

```
default: Box Provider: virtualbox

default: Box Version: ~> 20200304.0.0
```

==> default: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/bionic64'

```
default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/bionic64
```

==> default: Adding box 'ubuntu/bionic64' (v20200304.0.0) for provider: virtualbox

```
default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/bionic64/versions/20200304.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
```

Download redirected to host: cloud-images.ubuntu.com

```
default:
```

==> default: Successfully added box 'ubuntu/bionic64' (v20200304.0.0) for 'virtualbox'!

==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/bionic64'...

==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' version '20200304.0.0' is up to date...

==> default: Setting the name of the VM: profiles-rest-api_default_1685446821258_41886

Vagrant is currently configured to create VirtualBox synced folders with

the `SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate` option enabled. If the Vagrant

guest is not trusted, you may want to disable this option. For more

information on this option, please refer to the VirtualBox manual:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

This option can be disabled globally with an environment variable:

VAGRANT_DISABLE_VBOXSYMLINKCREATE=1

or on a per folder basis within the Vagrantfile:

config.vm.synced_folder '/host/path', '/guest/path', SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: false

==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...

==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...

```
default: Adapter 1: nat
```

==> default: Forwarding ports...

```
default: 8000 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)

default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
```

==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...

==> default: Booting VM...

==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

```
default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

default: SSH username: vagrant

default: SSH auth method: private key
```

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that

Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within

the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that

Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors

are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly

working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common

problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.

Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,

as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase

the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.

More time does not help... "config.ssh.timeout = 600"